# cygwin on windows does not recognize make

Tags: unix, cygwin

I am trying to use the make command in cygwin on windows but it says command not found .Please help on how to make it recognize the make command

Comment: Run cygwin's setup.exe again and make sure you have the package support for Makefiles. Should be under development, I believe.

Comment: It's called "make", in the "Devel" section.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In Cygwin, make is not installed by default. You need to launch Setup.Exe, select `make` in the `Devel` section, and let Setup download and install it.

Also, depending upon what you are building, you may need to install additional libraries for your build to work.